# How to do Taylor expansion of a differential form intrinsically?

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Let $(M,g)$ be a closed Riemannian manifold with Levi-Civita connection $\nabla$, let $\alpha$ be a n-form on $M$, let $P$ be a point in $M$.

My questions are (1) how could we do Taylor expansion of $\alpha$ at P in an intrinsic way? (2) Suppose $\alpha$ is parallel with $\nabla \alpha=0$, what will happen to that Taylor expansion?

Here is some thoughts of this question:

(1) We could choose some local coordinates at a neighborhood of P and choose a trivialization and a basis of the n-form bundle, then the Taylor expansion will be the expansion for the coefficients using these basis, but it doesn't look like a "good" definition as it depends on the trivialization.

(2) My guess is a Taylor expansion of $\alpha$ at $P$ would be the following: for $Q$ lies in a neighborhood of $P$, we pick a curve $\gamma(t)$ such that $\gamma(0)=P$ and $\gamma(1)=Q$, then the Taylor expansion of $\alpha$ at $Q$ would be
$$\alpha(Q)=\alpha|_P+\nabla_{\gamma'(0)}\alpha|_P+\nabla_{\gamma'(0)}\nabla_{\gamma'(0)}\alpha|_P+\cdots.$$
Here $\alpha(Q)$ is understood as using parallel transport of $\alpha|_Q$ to the fiber of n-forms at $P$ using the Levi-Civita connection. But I don't know how to prove it.

But one thing confuses me, suppose $\nabla\alpha=0$, then the Taylor series seems to be vanishes immediately? But the above Taylor series doesn't reflects any information of $\alpha$ in a neighborhood of $P$ even we know what $\alpha|_P$ is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fix any geodesic $\gamma\colon I \to M$ with $\gamma(0)=p\in M$. Define $\alpha'(0)=\nabla_{\gamma'(0)}\alpha|_p$, $\alpha''(0) =\nabla_{\gamma'(0)}\left(\nabla_{\gamma'(0)}\alpha\right)|_p$, etc. Consider their parallel transport along $\gamma$, still denoted by $\alpha'(0)$, $\alpha''(0)$, etc. Then the Taylor expansion of the coordinates of $\alpha$ in any parallel frame along $\gamma$ gives
$$
\alpha|_{\gamma(t)} \underset{t\to 0}{=} \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{\alpha^{(k)}(0)}{k!}t^k + O(t^{k+1}).
$$
Note that the coefficients $\alpha^{(k)}(0)$ depend smoothly on $\gamma'(0)$. Writing a point $q$ as $\exp_p(tv)$, we can explicit this dependance by writing
$$
\alpha|_{\exp_p(tv)} \underset{t\to 0}{=} \sum_{k=0}^{2n}\frac{\alpha^{(k)}(v)}{k!}t^k + O(t^{k+1}),
$$
where $\alpha^{(k)}(v) = \nabla_v\left( \nabla_v \cdots \left(\nabla_v \alpha\right)\right)|_p$.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. I have two questions: does it matter if we choose any curve instead of a geodesic for the first formula? Suppose we have a parallel form, is there a way to estimate the form near p using the value at p?

Comment: @SanJohn I choose to work with geodesics but this is not mandatory. It is just simpler here to do so: the exponential map, defined thanks to geodesics, handle all the directions at once and the formulae are nice